# how to avoid losing the completed fields in a view

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controllers with 2 views. view A contains several input text, checkbox, text fields etc. Clicking on a `<a>` on this form redirects me to view B. view B has a return to view `<a>` A.

How can I do so that when I return to view A, I do not miss the information on the form I previously filled out?
I'm not using ng-model because I just want to know how not to lose sight data. I do not think this matters or does it?

I understand the ngStorage and ng-model. but I want to know if there is any easier solution than saving the values ​​field by field ?. something like cache: true

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('A', {
        url: "/A",
        template: '<input type="text"><br><input type="checkbox"><br><input type="radio"><br><a ui-sref="B">NEXT</a>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log("A");
        }
    }).state('B', {
        url: "/B",
        template: '<a ui-sref="A">BACK</a>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log("B");
        }
    });
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
 $state.go("A");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rw645c89/

Comment: You don't even use the `ngModel` directive on your inputs

Comment: @AlonEitan I'm not using ng-model because I just want to know how not to lose sight data. I do not think this matters or does it?

Comment: It's very much matters :) This will help you [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) and you'll have to use `ngModel` in order for it to work

Comment: @AlonEitan I understand the localstorage and ng-model. but I want to know if there is any easier solution than saving the values ​​field by field ?. something like cache: true

Comment: No such thing AFAIK, and you either need to save it into a database (Which requires server side development knowledge), or you need to save the values on the client side (Which is made very easy using the ngStorage service)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use service to preserve data between states?

http://jsfiddle.net/b41uo73t/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {

$stateProvider.state('A', {
    url: "/A",
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="mainService.inputValue"><br><input type="checkbox" ng-model="mainService.checkboxValue_1"><br><input type="radio" ng-model="mainService.checkboxValue_2"><br><a ui-sref="B">NEXT</a>',
    controller: function ($scope, MainService) {
        console.log("A");
        $scope.mainService = MainService;
    }
}).state('B', {
    url: "/B",
    template: '<a ui-sref="A">BACK</a>',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        console.log("B");
    }
});
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
 $state.go("A");
})

.service('MainService', function() {
 this.inputValue = "";
  this.checkboxValue_1 = false;
    this.checkboxValue_2 = false;

});
```

Comment: "this" in general refers to the scope of the function. "this" in this context is the scope of MainService function. This is how we should declare variables in angular service. More reading about it https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/services-in-angularjs-simplified-with-examples